# Hashing algorithm with fixed range rather than fixed size output

Tags: hash, cryptanalysis

I have read that output that varies by key size or file size can leak information. So if it should produce fixed size then what is the scenario if it produces fixed range?

By fixed range I mean that for example, by hashing the word `"hello"` or by hashing 100 MB file produces the length not more than 320 digits long typically rendered as a hexadecimal number. In other words, 320 digit long is the maximum size irrespective of the input length.

So what would be the security issues in this case? Will it create a problem or is it okay? In this case is there any way that attacker can distinguish between various input size?

Comment: Please attack a link to where you read that "output that varies by key size or file size can leak information"

Comment: "... varies by key size" - there is typically no key involved with a plain cryptographic hash function. I suspect that hashing and encryption are being confused here. Are you sure the place where you saw this mentioned was talking about hashing and not encryption? Hash functions are typically defined as compressing an arbitrarily large input into a fixed-length output.

Comment: I think he meant hash-size, not key size.

Comment: Without clarification I guess that Baby desta's *guess* is the best one, but the second section completely wrong foots me. Please explain in other words what exactly you mean with "fixed-range". Do you mean a value that is between [0..N) where N may not be a power of two? Or do you mean a range of bits of (0..L] where L is 320 * 8 in your example?

Comment: So how  does the output size of the hash depend on the input size anyway? What kind of hash function are you using? Normal crypto hashes produce a specific output size (in bits / bytes) only.

Comment: @Maarten Bodewes ,in my example by fixed range i just mean to say that  it is producing not more than 320 digit long. Like in sha-1 it generates fixed 40 digit long output, in my case it generates in the range of [40,320]  and the maximum it can generate is 320 digit long and will not exceed this range irrespective of the input size. And I just wanted to know whether the output not being a fixed length instead in a range , effects the security issues in any way. And yes, I am speaking about the hash size not the key size. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @Maarten Bodewes, I am using the normal hash algorithm but with little modifications which generates the output in terms of range of bits. I have heard that (one of the reason)the hashes are meant to generate in terms of fixed length , otherwise it will be quite easy for  attacker to assume the length of the input. So, I wanted to know is there any chance that this can become true in my case of example.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming your question is that you want to know if a hash function which is of fixed-size hash is more secure than based on fixed-range hash is more secure.

Even if the hash is of a fixed range, whether it is secure or not depends on the hashing algorithm. Take for example, the following hash function:

$hr$
 where the output is a SHA-512 of the input message except that if the hash has leading zeros, they are cut out of it.(For example: if $\operatorname{SHA-512}(x) = \mathtt{0000EA34....}$, then $hr(x) = EA34...$). The maximum length of the hash is the length of the hash of SHA-512.

This fixed-range hash function is completely secure as long as SHA-512 is secure.